# Ensemble (Combine) multiple deep learning regression models which already have dropout layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, prediction, robust

Currently I have multiple trained models for regression task, each model is of the same architecture but while training, I have dropout layer, to improve the performance, is that still possible for me to combine those trained models and calculate the mean of the weights as the combined, new model? I just heard that there is an ensemble prediction method which allow us to do, but I am not sure whether I can still do this because I already have random dropout layer.

Any hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the presence of dropout is irrelevant to what you want to do. Ensembling should work just fine with dropout.